# dart/polymer style classes not working for imported dart files

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm probably making a big design mistake here.

I have a polymer template, "fred". So I have "fred.dart" and "fred.html".

"fred.dart" was getting rather large, so I split off a logical chunk of code, placed it in a new file called "child.dart", which I import into "fred.dart".

First, I tried creating a new *class* called "child" - being the whole of "child.dart". It's quite closely connected to "fred" but I can only use styles like:

```
    myPaperButton.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

The following method does not work:

```
    myPaperButton.classes=['mystyle'];
```

I have tried removing the "class child", but then I get a whole bunch of other problems.How can "child" call functions in "fred"? Is it possible?
 Or is my approach wrong - should I just merge "child.dart" back into "fred.dart"?
cheers
Steve

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is. I would be easier with some actual code which demonstrates what you tried. I don't understand at all what your question has to do with the CSS in the code lines above. To allow child call methods of fred just pass fred to child (in the contructor).

Answer (score 0):

The right code would be:

```
myPaperButton.classes.add('mystyle');
```

for adding a class and

```
myPaperButton.classes.remove('mystyle');
```

for removing a class. You can also use:

```
myPaperButton.classes.toggle('mystyle');
```

and

```
myPaperButton.classes.toggleAll('mystyle');
```